# Code-push releases well but doesn't arrive to the application

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, code-push

I'm using ionic 4 framework and i work on android app and everything good after that i try to release updates to my app using code-push-plugin i setup the code-push-cli and login to appcenter and install the plugin and import it into app.module and every thing is OK so i build a debug version using "ionic cordova build android" and make some changes in my app (to check the plugin) and use "code-push release-cordova MyApp android" to release update. it uploads well but never shown in my application

i check the appcenter and go to staging releases and i found my releases updates

here's my app.componant.ts file

```
import { CodePush } from '@ionic-native/code-push/ngx';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
   .
   .
   .
    private codePush: CodePush,
   .
  ) {

    this.initializeApp();
  }


  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      this.codePush.sync().subscribe((syncStatus) => console.log(syncStatus));

      const downloadProgress = (progress) => { console.log(`Downloaded 
      ${progress.receivedBytes} of ${progress.totalBytes}`); }
      this.codePush.sync({}, downloadProgress).subscribe((syncStatus) => 
      console.log(syncStatus));

   this.statusBar.styleDefault();
   this.splashScreen.hide();
});
}
```

and this is my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
..
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="CodePushDeploymentKey" value="TM8jRvULboCjSVhDzApTk6Yu7Kry97c78f7d-6a98-4378-a263-abd88ec58996" />
...
    </platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs. There should be `[CodePush]` tags and you should see some messages about checking updates.
If you see these messages then check the target binary version. It should be equals as your version of the app.
If you don't see these messages then it means that there is some issue in CodePush setup or configuration.